# django memcahed for post form generated page

Tags: python, django, post, memcached

Is it possible to use django and memcached for dynamic page that are generated by POST form method?

The reason I'd like to do this because some of my pages are taking long time for processing while the form input from users are occasionally simillar.

Answer (score 0):

Short: Yes

Not so short (but vague because of a vague question): First, find a way to build a cache key from the form values. Then on form submit, create the key and look in the cache and if there is no content with that key, create, store and return it. If there is content, return that. Maybe add and expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, you also don't have to cache the entire page. One strategy we've tried at our shop is rendering expensive snippets of HTML and storing them in memcached so that they can be included dynamically.

To do that, you wouldn't do render_to_response, but you would do manual rendering with Context and the template loader.

You have to make sure you have a good expiration policy and watch for race conditions, though.